# Setting a Dropdown list and Data bind in google map marker info window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I want to have a asp dropDownList in google map marker info window.Which means when i click the marker info window appears with a dropdownList set inside .
Here is my code. But when i do like this even my map is not loading...

```
  contentString = '<div style="overflow: auto;width: 275px;">' +
                       '<div id="RightSideMainDiv" class="col75" style="width:72%;">' +   
                       '<div> <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> </div>' +
                       '</div>';
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: url,
                        title: "Click",
                        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

                        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
```

Comment: need a help please :)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: this seems to be working can u provide the whole code may be there might be some problem ..

Comment: @Nitin sorry Nitin this is official stuff putting entire code may even be confused. Have you done this sort of a thing. By the way i put there a asp button successfully. but when it comes to the drop downlist it fails

Comment: i did this with html 
https://jsfiddle.net/nitinkolmi/jah5jrnb/embedded/result/

Comment: @Nitin there you have just coded option as first not setting a data source to get data from database. and you have put a <select></select> right? You know a way to bind data to html select ? thank you Nitin

Comment: In your contentString, I count three DIV tags, but at the end only two close DIV tags.  So you have a mismatch which may explain the map not loading part.  Given that @Niten showed you can do a dropdown in an InfoBox, you likely need to check what actual HTML gets sent to the client when the server-side ASP code resolves.

Comment: i believe you can bind with asp only you should try what @cybermike told you it might solve the problem

Comment: @cybermike nop i just edited from the my real code so that was a mistake. i want to know a way to set a data source to html select drop down

Comment: @Nitin asp dropdownList not working mate thats why...

Comment: i am not sure of this but give it a try and let me know
google gave me this :P
<SELECT id="someid" size="2" name="Select1" runat="server" 
   DataSource="<%# list %>" 
   DataMember="authors"
   DataTextField="au_lname" 
   DataValueField="au_id">
      <OPTION></OPTION>
</SELECT>

Comment: @Nitin didn't work.. Any way thanks a lot for the advises  Nitin.